# when will be factory registration will happen for the uvm testcase included in the package

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

For the testcase included in the test package, When will be  factory registration of UVM testcase will happen ? is during import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing packages is part of the compilation process before the execution of any code. UVM factory registration is tied to the initialization of static variables of parameterized classes at simulation time 0. (I have a [DVCon paper](https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/white-paper-using-parameterized-classes-and-factories-the-yin-and-yang-of-object) going over the details of that).

But this issue you may be facing is that you have put your test cases in a SystemVerilog `package` and never imported that package. There are different approaches to handling this depending on which tools you are using, and the compilation process you are using.